# Is the derivative of a Lipschitz function better than L^\infty

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, geometric-measure-theory

How smooth is the first derivative (in the distribution sense) of a Lipschitz function?  Taking difference quotients and testing against an $L^1$ function, we see that $Df$ is in $L^\infty$.  In ${\mathbb R}^1$ the converse is true, thanks to the persistence of the formula

$f(x+h) - f(x) = \int_0^1 f'(x+th) dt~ h$

(Proof: convolve with a mollifier)

However, if $f : {\mathbb R}^n \to {\mathbb R}$ is Lipschitz, then by the same argument, its derivative has a restriction to any line which is in $L^\infty$ of that line (more precisely, the tangential component of the derivative restricts).  Ordinarily, one cannot restrict a distribution sensibly to lower dimensional subsets (straight lines requiring even more regularity than curves), or at least if you can because its primitive restricts, I don't know of any reason to expect the restriction to have any semblance of regularity.

For $n > 1$, is there a nice Banach space in which the derivative of a Lipschitz function belongs whose elements are smoother than just $L^\infty$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lipschitz functions are exactly $W^{1,\infty}$ (See '[Sobolev space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space)' on wikipedia - under other examples and perhaps the bit about absolute continuity on lines). This means the short answer to your question is no.

Comment: Can you point me to a proof?  I was under this impression that there were non-Lipschitz $W^{1,\infty}$ functions in dimensions greater than 1.

Comment: Never mind, I have found a proof in Evans.

Comment: Of course, in higher dimensions the gradient can not be just any vector-valued $L^\infty$-function $f = (f_i)$, since it satisfies the distributional identity

$
\dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} = \dfrac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}.
$

So you don't get the whole of $L^\infty$, only those functions that satisfy this identity.

Comment: Mark -- I think your remark here was the (fairly obvious but nonetheless fundamental) thing I was failing to realize.  It's just that this particular system of PDE does not exactly bestow upon its solutions any additional regularity.

Answer (score 2):

Every Lipschitz function is absolutely continuous.  Consequently, its derivative exists and is uniformly bounded almost everywhere.  The Lipschitz constant is just the $L^\infty$ norm of the derivative.

If you want a Banach space of smoother functions, then just define it.  For example, let $X$ be the space of Lipschitz functions on $\mathbb R^n$ with integrable derivatives:  $$X = \{ f :~ \nabla f \in L^1 \cap L^\infty \}.$$